# Operators in a table

Tags: java, stringbuilder

There are 7 rows of output for table, how can I modify this so row 6 displays either of the three providers.

I tried something like this :

```
template.getProvider2() != null || template.getProvider3() != null ||
template.getProvider1() != null ? 
template.getProvider2().getBusinessUnit(): "" || 
template.getProvider3().getBusinessUnit(): "" || 
template.getProvider3().getBusinessUnit(): "",
```

which gives me an error of StringBuilder not accepting the OR operator,
I'd appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
public GetEmailTemplatesResponse getEmailTemplates() throws Exception {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String tableRow = "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>";
        Map<String, EmailTemplate> templates = templateRedisCacheReader.getTemplatesByCacheType(CacheType.EMAIL_TEMPLATE);
        templates.values()
                .forEach(template -> stringBuilder.append(String.format(tableRow,
                        template.getTemplateId(),
                        template.getProvider1() != null ? template.getProvider1().getId() : "",
                        template.getProvider2() != null ? template.getProvider2().getId() : "",
                        template.getProvider3() != null ? template.getProvider3().getId() : "",
                        template.getEnv(),
                        template.getProvider2() != null ? template.getProvider2().getBusinessUnit(): "",  // <--
                        template.getPriority()))
                );
```

I tried to check if all the providers are null and if one of them is not null , then display bussiness unit for that provider

Answer (score 0):

There's a function commonly used in SQL that returns the first non-null parameter called "coalesce".  You could write a Java equivalent of that.

```
Object coalesce(Object... objects) {
    for (Object obj : objects) {
        if(obj != null) return obj;
    }
    return null;
}
... 
Provider firstNonNullTemplate=(Provider) coalesce(template.getProvider1(), template.getProvider2(), template.getProvider3());
```